# Azure Service Accounts set password to never expire

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to import service accounts from a csv file and turn those service accounts passwords to never expire in Azure.

Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId  -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment password is set to the user to never expire successfully:***

```
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId <user ID> -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId <user ID> | fl
```

[image]

To Set a ***password never expire for multiple users of CSV file*** make use of below cmdlet:

```
Import-CSV azureadusers.csv | ForEach {
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.AzureADUPN -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
}
```

To check whether the password expiry has been set correctly use below command:

```
Import-CSV azureadusers.csv | ForEach { Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.AzureADUPN | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ` @{N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}
```

***Reference:*** [Set an password to never expire - | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/set-password-to-never-expire?view=o365-worldwide)

### Update

### [image]

Comment: The following isn't working: $connect = Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $env:USERNAME@allina.com
Import-CSV -Path "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\azureadusers.csv" | ForEach {
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.AzureADUPN -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
} I get Error: The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteHashLiteral

Comment: [on3N3xus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984313/on3n3xus) please check the updated answer